# What is a good free tool to manage projects in Java?

Tags: java, project-management

I need a tool to manage a project that I developing, but I don't know what to use.

Many are the requirements, I need a tool to manage the TO DO things, the bugs found with tools like FindBugs, PMD, etc., the text documentation, the UML, versions, backup, etc.

In another words, all that is possible to manage, but I need a tool like this to manage various aspects of the project. Maybe something integrated with Eclipse.

What tools are recommended for this?

Example: I know that Sonar is useful for manage the bugs found, but other things I don't know.

EDIT: There is a portable bug tracker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need *a* tool?  As in one?

That's not, in general, how projects are managed, ime.

For todo and bugs, Trac is good (and integrated with Eclipse), though if you're willing to spend $10, I personally prefer JIRA.

For versions and backup, that's version control: subversion or git.  Both are integrated with eclipse.

For documentation and uml, I'm not sure what you mean by *manage* - just making sure you don't lose them?  version control again.  Documenting what exists?  Wiki's pretty good.

Comment: No, not all in only ONE tool, but something integrated like the tools that you and the others cited.

Comment: Use wiki to documentation looks interesting. There is some "wiki server" that can I have in my pendrive?

Comment: @Renato I've never tried to run this stuff off of a pen drive, but I'd look at DocuWiki.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to use Netbeans IDE quite a bit because it is also able to open and edit Eclipse projects so it tends to be a very versatile IDE. It also features a Visual GUI Builder.

Comment: I using both Eclipse and Netbeans. I guess that Netbeans is best for editing and debugging, but Eclipse there a lot more of plugins.

Comment: That's true as well. Yeah I used to use Eclipse a lot but then when I started it on a different computer with a different scratch drive, every line of code had an error. But, yeah you're right.

Answer (score 2):

You might look at Trac.   It works well with Subversion.

http://trac.edgewall.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for Open Source solution, I found these best

- [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/)
- [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/)

Both of them easy integration with eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Some open source project management tools in java

[Open Source Project Management Tools in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/project-management)

[Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)

[Open Source Issue Tracking Software in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/issue-trackers)

[Source Control Tools in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/source-control)

[Open Source IDEs in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/ides)

[Open Source UML & Modeling in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/uml-modeling)

[Open Source Validation Frameworks](http://java-source.net/open-source/validation)

[Open Source Web Testing Tools in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/web-testing-tools)

[Open Source Logging Tools in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/logging)

[Open Source Web Frameworks in Java](http://java-source.net/open-source/web-frameworks)